# How to get an access token if the application is already connected to Dropbox?

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

I ran into such a problem. I would like to have access to the user's Dropbox (to the folder of my application). I use one of the authorization flow that Dropbox provides. The flow at which the `access_token` is returned as a hash parameter in the `redirect_uri`.

**At the first connection**, everything works correctly: the user is redirected to the authorization page, confirms the application’s access to Dropbox and, if successful, is redirected to the redirect_uri with the access_token.

But when I try to **connect again** (**only if I use the Safari** (version I'm using: 13.1),  **redirect occurs without an access_token**. The address is as follows: `"https://mysite/redirect_uri#"`. All the same works correctly in Chrome and Firefox.

But if I sign out from the account right on the Dropbox website, the authorization will work correctly.

Comment: Can you share more specific steps to reproduce this issue? I just tried reproducing this from your description using the Dropbox API OAuth 2 'token' flow repeatedly in Safari 13.1 and the `#access_token=...` was present each time for me.

Comment: @Greg Hello! Thank you for responding to my question. Each time, I redirect the user to the following address: https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=`clientId`&response_type=token&redirect_uri=`url`&state=`state`. The first time the user allows access to the application, the token is returned correctly. But if the user is redirected to this link a second time: the user automatically logs in (if he himself did not exit the account) and then redirect to my `redirect_uri`, but unfortunately without a token or some kind of error.

Comment: I just tried this using that URL format but it still works for me. Did you have a live demo of this issue you can share, or otherwise can you share a screencast showing the issue?

Comment: @Greg Hey. Now I use OAuth 2.0 authorization flow in which I get the code, and then the access token. Everything works correctly, regardless of browser. Thank you for your time.